# How to check if any thread(CompletableFuture) is not finished in While condition in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing, completable-future

I am setting up a web crawler and want to support multi-thread processing. A seed URL may return numerous URLs. A loop is set for keep generating thread(CompletableFuture) to crawl a URL.

**I encounter a problem of setting the While condition. How can I check if all CompletableFuture is finished(Or any of them is not finished)?**

Two ways in my mind which might works:

1. Create a AtomicInteger and use Increment and Decrement to record a CompletableFuture is created and finished. Check it in every loop
2. Create a list to store every CompletableFuture and check if all done in every loop

Both ways shall work but these might not be best approaches. Looking forward for any other ways.

It would be fine even replacing CompletableFuture with Future, Callable, Runnable, Executor, etc... It is also fine if someone can post design which completion of all threads do not need to be considered.

```
//queue for storing urls
    this.unvisitedURLsAndPaths = new ConcurrentLinkedDeque<>();

//Loop If we can poll a url with path from the queue Or any crawler has not finished its job
while ((urlAndPath=this.unvisitedURLsAndPaths.pollLast())!=null/*OR ANY CRAWLER HAS NOT FINISHED ITS JOB*/) {

    // If we have the url with path
    if (urlAndPath!=null){
        //remember the url and path for filtering by crawlers

            this.visitedURLsAndPaths.put(urlAndPath[0],urlAndPath[1]);

            //give the url and path to the crawler
            Crawler crawler = new Crawler(urlAndPath[0], urlAndPath[1], this);

            //crawlers do the job(get new urls with paths and filter them) and they would offer the result(a collection of unvisited urls with paths) to the queue
            CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(()->crawler.work());

    }
}
```

Comment: nothing wrong in this approach `Create a list to store every CompletableFuture and check if all done in every loop`